# How to create a google Oauth in spring?

Tags: spring, google-oauth, spring-boot

I'm new to spring so bear with me :o

I'm using Spring Boot v1.1.8.RELEASE

I'm trying to get a working google Oauth connection with my website.

So I'm trying to get the spring-social-google working while the twitter & facebook one are working.

I read this http://gabiaxel.github.io/spring-social-google-reference/overview.html
I read the tutorial from Spring.io for the other providers(twitter & Facebook).

So here is the code I have :

```
package app.controllers;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.social.google.api.Google;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/google")
public class GoogleController {

    private Google google;

    @Inject
    public GoogleController(Google google) {
        this.google = google;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param model
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloGoogle(Model model) {
        if (!google.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/google";
        }

        model.addAttribute(google.plusOperations().getGoogleProfile());
        return "testGoogle";
    }

}
```

- I have the files like for facebook in my templates a
  googleConnect.html and a googleConnected.html.
- Maven is importing correctly the dependencies
- The application.properties have the secret and appid from a google
  App I created

Here is the error I have :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name    'googleController' defined in file [C:\Users\Antoine\Documents\NetBeansProjects\p0907931-cinemagik\app\target\classes\app\controllers\GoogleController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.social.google.api.Google]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.google.api.Google] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.google.api.Google] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The bean should be autowired like the other providers right ?

Thanks for your time.

edit :

This bean is working but I don't know how to implement it in my controller ?

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new GoogleConnectionFactory(
            environment.getProperty("superAPI"),
            environment.getProperty("superSecret")));

        return registry;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot only has autoconfig support for Spring Social with Twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn (not Google). You can probably copy the code from the existing implementations and adapt it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/social.

Comment: Hi, do you know how come not google? And anyone know where we can get an implementation for google? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
package app.controllers;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.social.google.api.Google;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class GoogleController {

    private Google google;

    @Inject
    public GoogleController(Google google) {
        this.google = google;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param model
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value="/google")
    public String helloGoogle(Model model) {
        if (!google.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/google";
        }

        model.addAttribute(google.plusOperations().getGoogleProfile());
        return "testGoogle";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but I got the same error :                                                                                      2014-11-16 10:48:29.578 ERROR 428 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'googleController' defined in ...